# Powershell Script Create Bulk Users and assign them to multiple groups

Tags: powershell, import, active-directory

I've been working on a script that imports users in the Active Directory assigned to multiple groups through PowerShell. The script is working fine, but I'd like to know if I can improve the script and maybe you guys have any suggestions or improvements on the script?

**Powershell Script: Import_BulkUsers.ps1**

```
$CSVFile = "Gebruikers.csv"

$users = Import-Csv $CSVFile -delimiter ";"

$users | ForEach-Object {
    # Domain data
    $OU = $_.Afdeling
    $DomainName = "LAN.CONTOSO.COM"

    # User data
    $voornaam = $_.Voornaam
    $tussenvoegsel = $_.Tussenvoegsel
    $achternaam = $_.Achternaam
    $password = "Password1"
    $username = $voornaam.Substring(0,3) + $achternaam.Substring(0,2)

    if($tussenvoegsel -eq "") { 
        $Displayname= $voornaam + " " + $achternaam 
    } else {
        $Displayname= $voornaam + " " + $tussenvoegsel + " " + $achternaam
    }

    # Userprofile & Homefolder
    $homefolderdrive = "Z:"
    $homefolder = "\\"+$_.SRV+"\"+$_.HF+"$\"+$username
    $profilefolder = "\\"+$_.SRV+"\"+$_.UP+"$\"+$username

    # Secure password
    $SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force

    $UserPrincipalName = $username+"@"+$DomainName

    $userExists = (Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $username }) 

        if($userExists -eq $null) {
            # New AD user 
            New-ADUser -Name $Displayname -GivenName $voornaam -Surname $achternaam -DisplayName $Displayname -SamAccountName $username -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -HomeDrive $homefolderdrive -HomeDirectory $homefolder -ProfilePath $profilefolder -Path $OU -AccountPassword $SecurePass -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Enabled $True

            # Add users to Global Groups
            $Groups = ($_.GroupName).split(",")
            foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
                    Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $username -MemberOf $Group
            }

            # Create homefolder
            New-Item $homefolder -Itemtype Directory | Out-Null

            Write-Host "You've created a new user:" $Displayname -fore "Green"
            Write-Host "`n"
        } else {
            # Display error on screen
            Write-Host "Not imported user:" -Fore "Yellow"
            Write-Host "User '$Displayname' already exists" -Fore "Red"
            Write-Host "`n"

            # Function write error to file
            function writetoPath() {
            $dateNow = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy @ hh:mm:ss"
            $existingUser = "User '$Displayname' already exists"
            "$dateNow   //   $existingUser" >> C:\LogFiles\PowerShell\Import_Gebruikers.txt
            }

            # Create Path if doesn't exists
            $logfilesPath = "C:\LogFiles\PowerShell"
            if (!(Test-Path $logfilesPath)) {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $logfilesPath
                writetoPath
            } else {
                writetoPath
            }
            }
}
```

**CSV file: Gebruikers.csv**
[Gebruikers.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO3G7.png)

Comment: This sounds more like a question for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consult the PowerShell style guide more, this makes the script easier to read and modify in the future. Also you should use a lot more error handling in your script.

for instance adding error handling and making it yourself easy:

```
foreach($Group in $Groups){
    try{
        Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $username -MemberOf $Group
        Write-Host "Successfully added groupmembership for '$username' to '$group'" -ForegroundColor Green
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Failed to add groupmembership for '$username' to '$group'" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

And for the next one also definitely advise to use try/catch, because the script stops if for instance 1 value is not correct.

```
try{ 
    New-ADUser -Name $Displayname -GivenName $voornaam -Surname $achternaam -DisplayName $Displayname -SamAccountName $username -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -HomeDrive $homefolderdrive -HomeDirectory $homefolder -ProfilePath $profilefolder -Path $OU -AccountPassword $SecurePass -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Enabled $True
}catch{
    Write-Host "Failed to create AD user '$Displayname'" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

What you can do to prevent empty values to the New-ADUser CMDlet is for instance:

```
foreach($user in $users){
    $params = @{}
    if($user.Voornaam){
        $params += @{
            givenName = $user.Voornaam
        }
    }
    if($user.Achternaam){
        $params += @{
            surName = $user.Achternaam
        }
    }
    try{
        New-ADUser @params
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Failed to create AD user '$($user.displayName)'" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

This way you make it far more easier! Hope this helps.

Good luck

Comment: Hi Bernard, thanks for the advice. You gave me a great example of how to apply Try & Catch. This helps a lot. Great work.

Comment: But I don't quite understand the "$params = @{}" stuff, can you explain what this does?

Comment: Glad my example helped. At the $params I declare a hash table. When I say "$whatever = @{}" $whatever becomes an empty hashtable. For each user an empty hash table is declared, after that, we fill it with all the name + values that exist. When I add @whatever to the cmdlet, all name/value combinations from the hash table are added to the CMDlet New-UserAD. I strongly recommend getting familiar with hash tables and arrays. Always beware of the type of variable you are working with. Try "$whatever.GetType()" to check the variable type (hasttable, string, integer, psobject etc).

Comment: All right, thank you for the explanation buddy. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you mean how to add multiple users in one shot, you may try something like this

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$user1 = [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]@{GivenName="John"; Surname="Doe"; SamAccountName = "JohnDoe"}

$user2 = [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]@{GivenName="John"; Surname="Smith"; SamAccountName = "JohnSmith"}


$users = $user1, $user2

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "YOUR-AD-GROUP" -Members $users
```

So it's just general idea, you'd need to test/adjust it. Not sure if it's any better than your original code though.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I already have something similar in my script, but your code is also great, thank you.